# Does having an SHA256 hash compromise PBKDF2 secrecy?

Tags: sha-256, pbkdf-2, password-hashing, password-based-encryption

If I have a password `pwd`, and I hash it with `SHA256` and send it to a server for authentication (server will apply `bcrypt` for storage), and then I use `PBKDF2-SHA256` with a large number of iterations to derive a key for decrypting user data, does the fact that the server knows the original `SHA256` hash or the `bcrypt` hash allow it to derive the original `pwd` or the decryption key?

Another way to phrase the question: see below pseudocode

```
CLIENT:
hash1 := SHA256(email + pwd)
> send hash1 to server

SERVER:
hash2 := bcrypt(hash1)
if hash2 == stored expected value; send data and salt back to client

CLIENT
key := pbkdf2(email + pwd, salt, ...)
AES.decrypt(data, key)
```

In my scenario, the `SERVER` is a third party. If, say, the server went rogue and tried to steal all of the users' data, would the server be able to do so easily, knowing about the contents of `hash1` and `salt`?

> P.S.: Does 5 million iterations somehow weaken PBKDF2 (hash cycles, etc.)?

Comment: Yes, a single round of SHA-256 allows for extremely fast brute-forcing. That is if `pwd` is a bad password, it can be found very quickly by a malicious server.

Comment: Well now I know not to develop security-related ideas when I haven’t got enough sleep ‍♂️

Comment: Related question about a curiously similar scenario (but without the client-side key derivation part): https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6280/hashing-a-password-with-sha256-on-the-client-then-bcrypt-on-the-server

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Saw that one. But I was thinking more along the lines of if knowing a SHA256 hash weakens the pbkdf2. But regardless the hash can be just brute forced anyway defeating the purpose of the iteration count of the pbidf2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the party that controls the server also controls the client application then the server will always be able to retrieve the password. In that sense protecting against the server only works if very strict auditing is taking place, and then only maybe.

If the server receives a hash over the password then it can of course perform a (augmented) dictionary attack against the hash. When multiple hashes are collected then rainbow tables will also be an option. All the additional protection delivered by bcrypt of PBKDF2 will be null and void.

So yes, **if** the password could be found with an attack, and then PBKDF2 can be performed using the found password in your scheme. Very strong password will still offer protection against the server, of course.

---

PS No, the more iterations the better for PBKDF2. Cycles only occur after many more iterations, and are nothing to worry about here.