# Secure hash with digest size 128 bit?

Tags: hash, md5

MD5 has a digest size of 128 bits but has long been discouraged.

Is there an alternative algorithm with 128 bit digest size which is still considered secure?

Comment: Near cuplicate of [What is the recommended replacement for MD5?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/what-is-the-recommended-replacement-for-md5), where [my answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3001/555) discusses repalcement with a 128-bit hash.

Comment: TL;DR: No. A 128-bit hash requires 2^64 attempts to find a collision. This is within the means of big organisations today. 256-bit hashes should be fine the next 50 years if hardware development is no faster than Moore's law, and if no weaknesses are found in the algorithm.